# Error in getting list from SQL view through JPA Creteria Query

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have created SQL view in Mysql database. I am writing web service to show list using JPA based on user search entry. Hibernate query is executing correctly in console, but list is not showing when checked in advaced rest client. Please check below for required code:

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbi_datadiscovery_detail_view"/*, catalog = "timebound"*/)
public class TbiDDDetailView implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields
    @Id
    @Column(name = "dd_metric_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "ddConfigId"))
    private Integer ddConfigId;  

    @Column(name="dd_metric_name")
    private String  metricName;

    @Column(name="dd_type")
    private String ddType;

    @Column(name="dd_name")
    private String ddName;

    @Column(name="discovery_id")
    private Integer discoveryId;

    @Column(name="key_words")
    private String keywords;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private TbiDDConfigMaster tbiDDConfigMaster;  

//setters & getters

}
```

JPA Repository:

```
public interface TbiDDDetailViewDao extends CrudRepository<TbiDDDetailView, Integer>, JpaRepository<TbiDDDetailView, Integer> {

    @Query("select v from TbiDDDetailView v,TbiDDConfigMaster t where v.ddConfigId = t.ddConfigId and t.domainId=?1 and v.metricName LIKE %?2% or t.keywords LIKE %?2%")
List<TbiDDDetailView> findByDomainIdAndMetricNameLike(Integer domainId,String metricName);

}
```

Service Implementation:

```
public TbiDDDetailViewListResponse getViewMatrics(List sortProperties, List sortTypes,
        List operator, List value, List property, int page, int limit,
        Integer domainId, String searchString) {

    TbiDDDetailViewListResponse res = new TbiDDDetailViewListResponse();
    List<TbiDDDetailView> tbiDDDetailViews  = tbiDDDetailViewDao.findByDomainIdAndMetricNameLike(domainId, searchString);

        CriteriaBuilder cb=em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<TbiDDDetailView> qry =cb.createQuery(TbiDDDetailView.class);
        Root root = qry.from(TbiDDDetailView.class);
        Root config = qry.from(TbiDDConfigMaster.class);

        List creteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
        Predicate predicate1 = cb.equal(root.get("tbiDDConfigMaster").get("ddConfigId"), config.get("ddConfigId"));
        creteriaList.add(predicate1);

        Predicate predicate2 = cb.equal(root.get("tbiDDConfigMaster").get("ddConfigId"), domainId);
        creteriaList.add(predicate2);

        Predicate predicate3 = cb.like(cb.upper(root.get("metricName")),searchString);
        creteriaList.add(predicate3); 

        CriteriaQuery<TbiDDDetailView> criteriaQuery = qry.select(cb.construct(TbiDDDetailView.class, root.get("ddConfigId"),root.get("metricName"),root.get("ddType"),
                root.get("ddName"),root.get("discoveryId")));


        List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
        orderList = getSort(cb,root,sortProperties, sortTypes, null);

        qry.where(cb.and((Predicate[]) creteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[0])));

        int start=0;
        if(limit != 0) 
        start=(page-1)*limit;

        TypedQuery<TbiDDDetailView> tq = em.createQuery(qry);
        tbiDDDetailViews = tq.setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(limit).getResultList();
        TypedQuery<TbiDDDetailView> queryTotal = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        long totalRecords = (long) queryTotal.getResultList().size();

        List<DDDetailViewResponse> details = new ArrayList<>();

        if(tbiDDDetailViews!=null)
        {
            for(TbiDDDetailView t : tbiDDDetailViews){
                DDDetailViewResponse detailView = new DDDetailViewResponse();
                detailView.setDdMetricId(t.getDdConfigId());
                detailView.setDdMetricName(t.getMetricName());
                detailView.setDdType(t.getDdType());
                detailView.setDdName(t.getDdName());
                detailView.setDiscoveryId(t.getDiscoveryId());
                details.add(detailView);
                System.out.println("name-->"+t.getDdName()+"------type-------"+t.getDdType()+"-------------id--------------"+t.getDdConfigId()+"---------Metricname-----------"+t.getMetricName());
            }
        }
        res.setRecords(details);
        res.setPageNumber(page);
        if(limit != 0) {
            int Rem = (totalRecords%limit)>0?new Integer(1):0;
            int total = (int) (totalRecords/limit + Rem);
            res.setTotalPages(total);
            log.info("TotalRecords :"+totalRecords + "Total Pages:" +total);
        }           
        return res;

}
```

When I checked with debugging mode, execution is not going inside for loop only, its directly coming out of loop.

Hibernate query execution in console:

```
Hibernate: select tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_id as dd_metri1_34_, tbidddetai0_.dd_name as dd_name2_34_, tbidddetai0_.dd_type as dd_type3_34_, tbidddetai0_.discovery_id as discover4_34_, tbidddetai0_.key_words as key_word5_34_, tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_name as dd_metri6_34_ from tbi_datadiscovery_detail_view tbidddetai0_ cross join tbi_dd_config_master tbiddconfi1_ where tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_id=tbiddconfi1_.dd_metric_config_id and tbiddconfi1_.domain_id=? and (tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_name like ?) or tbiddconfi1_.keywords like ?
Hibernate: select tbiddconfi0_.dd_metric_config_id as dd_metri1_35_0_, tbiddconfi0_.created_by as created_2_35_0_, tbiddconfi0_.created_date as created_3_35_0_, tbiddconfi0_.domain_id as domain_i4_35_0_, tbiddconfi0_.is_active as is_activ5_35_0_, tbiddconfi0_.keywords as keywords6_35_0_, tbiddconfi0_.metric_name as metric_n7_35_0_, tbiddconfi0_.modified_by as modified8_35_0_, tbiddconfi0_.modified_date as modified9_35_0_ from tbi_dd_config_master tbiddconfi0_ where tbiddconfi0_.dd_metric_config_id=?
Hibernate: select tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_id as col_0_0_, tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_name as col_1_0_, tbidddetai0_.dd_type as col_2_0_, tbidddetai0_.dd_name as col_3_0_, tbidddetai0_.discovery_id as col_4_0_ from tbi_datadiscovery_detail_view tbidddetai0_ cross join tbi_dd_config_master tbiddconfi1_ where tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_id=tbiddconfi1_.dd_metric_config_id and tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_id=4926 and (upper(tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_name) like ?) limit ?
Hibernate: select tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_id as col_0_0_, tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_name as col_1_0_, tbidddetai0_.dd_type as col_2_0_, tbidddetai0_.dd_name as col_3_0_, tbidddetai0_.discovery_id as col_4_0_ from tbi_datadiscovery_detail_view tbidddetai0_ cross join tbi_dd_config_master tbiddconfi1_ where tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_id=tbiddconfi1_.dd_metric_config_id and tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_id=4926 and (upper(tbidddetai0_.dd_metric_name) like ?)
95953 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] INFO  com.acinfotech.timebound.jpa.service.ReportJobsPersistenceServiceImpl  - TotalRecords :0Total Pages:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it working by changing `Creteria query` with `Predicate`

Check below code that has worked for me:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb=em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<TbiDDDetailView> qry =cb.createQuery(TbiDDDetailView.class);
            Root root = qry.from(TbiDDDetailView.class);
            Root config = qry.from(TbiDDConfigMaster.class);

            List creteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
            Predicate predicate1 = cb.equal(root.get("tbiDDConfigMaster").get("ddConfigId"), config.get("ddConfigId"));
            creteriaList.add(predicate1);

            Predicate predicate2 = cb.equal(root.get("tbiDDConfigMaster").get("domainId"), domainId);
            creteriaList.add(predicate2);

            Predicate predicate3 = cb.or(cb.like(cb.upper(root.get("tbiDDConfigMaster").get("keywords")), "%"+searchString+"%"), cb.like(cb.upper(root.get("metricName")),"%"+searchString+"%"));

            CriteriaQuery<TbiDDDetailView> criteriaQuery = qry.select(cb.construct(TbiDDDetailView.class, root.get("ddConfigId"),root.get("metricName"),root.get("ddType"),
                    root.get("ddName"),root.get("discoveryId")));

            qry.where(cb.and((Predicate[]) creteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[0])), predicate3);  

TypedQuery<TbiDDDetailView> tq = em.createQuery(qry);  
return tq.getResultList();
```